# Creating custom router get to 404 page

Tags: module, magento-1, 404-page, router

I created my custom module under local the name is MyTest/ProductsData, what I need to do is to create the new router so I've been created the IndexController.php and my config.xml, and I already activated my custom module and I checked under system->configuration->advanced which is enabled, the URL I'm trying to test is http://example.com/magento/MyTest/index/ or http://example.com/magento/index.php/MyTest/index/index and any other possible URLs also I tried them, all will go to 404 page and I cannot find any solution to solve this problem :( I really appreciate if any of you can help me out with this.

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class MyTest_ProductsData_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
         echo 'me';
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'Test add Action';
    }
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        echo 'Test delete Action';
    }
}
```

and config.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyTest_ProductsData>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyTest_ProductsData>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mytest_productsdata>
                <class>MyTest_ProductsData_Helper</class>
            </mytest_productsdata>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <MyTest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyTest_ProductsData</module>
                    <frontName>MyTest</frontName>
                </args>
            </MyTest>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

Comment: May be controller file permission is not set to 777.

Comment: I already changed the permission to 777 :(

Comment: Run compilation and remove cache too..

Comment: yeah did it already cannot get to the right page :( still get to 404 page!

Comment: check is your controller file exist in magento includes->src->MyTest->ProductsData directory .

Comment: Under includes I can see config.php file if I uncomment the first line for src I can see the blank page !

Comment: No that is not. i am saying inside your magento directory check `includes` folder..

Comment: hmm under the includes folder I just can see config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have `MyTest_ProductsData.xml` inside your `app->etc->modules` directory create first..

If you have created already,then check your folder structure and give 777 permission to your module root directory `MyTest`.

After this Run Compilation process in admin and clear the cache and then check .

**EDIT**

I have tried your code and it worked for me with this url `localhost/magento/MyTest/`. Try again..

**FILES**

[controller](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9595085/), [config.xml](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9595088/) .

Comment: I have, actually I've activated my module inside that file then already checked it through admin panel, system->configuration->advanced, is enabled.

Comment: @SaghiGhorbani I've edited my answer check it now.

Comment: I already run compilation process in admin and clear the cache Disabled everything under cache storage management and clear cache again and I tried with the link you gave its so strange It still doesn't work for me  !! :(

Comment: Finally, it worked , thanks for your help :), the problem was I should put the routeName before UrlName, defined in config.xml

Comment: @SaghiGhorbani sounds good..

Answer (score -1):

Your router has to be as this.

```
<?php 

class Test_Modulename_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {

    public function initControllerRouters($observer) {

        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();

        $pressrelease  = 'custom_url_identifier';

        $front->addRouter($pressrelease, $this);     

        }

     public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) {  
         if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }

        $router_name = 'custom_router_name';
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if($router_name != $identifier)
        {
             $pressUrl = explode("/",$identifier);
             $pressUrl = $pressUrl[1];
             if($pressUrl != "")
             {
             }
                $collection = Mage::getModel('pressrelease/pressrelease')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('url',$pressUrl);
             if(count($collection))
             {
                 foreach ($collection as $_press)
                 {
                    $pressId = $_press['pressrelease_id'];
                    $pressName = $_press['title'];

                       $request->setModuleName('pressrelease')
                        ->setControllerName('pressitem')
                        ->setActionName('view')
                        ->setParam('pressrelease_id', $pressId)
                       ->setParam('title', $pressName);
                       return true;
                 }
             }else
             {
                 $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig('cms/index/noRoute');
                 $url = rtrim(Mage::getUrl($pageId),'/');
                 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                 return false;
             }
        }

        $request->setModuleName('pressrelease')
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('index');

        return true;

     }

}
```

In the events section of config.xml, add this:

```
 <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <modulesname>
                        <class>Test_Modulename_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                    </modulesname>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
```

Comment: Sry u mean I need to create another file under Controller named Router.php and put this code in?

Comment: I got 'Front controller reached 100 router match iterations' this error !

Comment: You need to comment the frontend section in the config.xml, when you are using this method.